# Windows PowerShell Tab Size

Tags: tabs, powershell-ise

I've started using PowerShell.

The tab size is 8 spaces.

I don't want that - I want 4 spaces.

How do I achieve this please?

Comment: In which editor?  In PowerShell ISE it's 4 spaces.  I use Visual Studio Code, which is a lot more advanced and is easy to modify.

Comment: I think in ISE the default is 4 spaces, I don't think there is a way to change that